# I clip a raster with a vector mask in qgis, the result is correct but its a little bit of, why is this?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, clip

On one side the result is "bleeding" over the vector on the other side its more than one raster pixel from the vector on the inside.

How to correct this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMiW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV5dP.png

Comment: Add small raster and vector file which can be used for reproducing the issue.

Comment: I tried the same raster but with a smaller vector mask and it works perfectly, do you have any suggestions on why?